# Moving a file in git history

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

In my feature branch I have about 50 commits. In the first commit I created a file that gets modified a lot in subsequent commits. I now realise it would be better to store that file in a different directory, so I'd like to go back to the first commit and just create it in the right place to begin with, to keep the history clean. I can do this with an interactive rebase by editing the first commit and moving the file, but then all of the subsequent commits that touch that file will produce conflicts that I have to manually resolve. Is there a way to tell every commit that the file has been moved, so they just automatically apply their changes in the right place?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask *why* you need to do this? It's a pretty strange thing, to need to move a file in previous commits. Occaisionally the need arises to *remove* a file, or to alter its content, but I can't really think of a case where it would be important to move it in history.

Comment: I agree, it might be good to know why you want to do this. From your description I don't see the necessity to change the git history.

Comment: Updated the question to make it clear that I realised it would be better to store the file in a different directory. There are many reasons why you might want to do this.

Comment: "*I'd like to go back to the first commit and just create it in the right place to begin with, to keep the history clean.*" This is not necessary. Git can track history across renames. `git blame` will by default. When getting the log of a single file use `git log --follow <file>`. Deep rewrites of history could break those commits making `git bisect` useless. And there's the problem of coordinating the rewritten history with other developers. It's better to assume there are renames in your history and use the tools than to try and eliminate them.

Comment: Looking at this as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), could you tell us what sort of problems the rename causing? Or what problems you anticipate?

Comment: @Schwern "This is not necessary. Git can track history across renames" - yes of course, but as I said I'm just working on a feature branch, so I'd rather make the history as clean as possible before merging, to make it easier for the rest of the team to understand.

Comment: @Schwern "what problems you anticipate?" - it's in the question - if I go back and move the file in the first commit, then every subsequent commit that touches that file (and there are lots of them) will cause a conflict that I have to manually resolve. It seems like there should be a way to tell git the file has moved so it updates all the commits to be applying the changes to the new file instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use `git filter-branch`.  You can use the `--index-filter` for speed but this is harder to use; with just 50-ish commits, use `--tree-filter` which is much slower but much easier to use:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter <fill this in> --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

You should generally do this on a *copy* (clone) of the original repository since it's easy to goof up the filter-branch and the easy way to *recover* from that is to remove the copy and start over.

Once it works, remove all the `refs/original/` names as described in [the `git filter-branch` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html).  The repository will eventually de-bloat (the filter-branch will roughly double it in size temporarily).

#### Long

History, in Git, is (are?) the commits.  To change history, you need to copy the old commits (which provide the old history) to new, different commits (which provide the new history).  So your goal is to replace all 50-ish commits with new ones that are the same *except* that the file is relocated to some other path.

As you mentioned, you *can* do this with interactive rebase, but it's a pain: rebase works by converting each commit-to-copy to a changeset (by comparing that commit to its parent, to see what changed) and then applying the same changes to some existing commit.

There is a rather heavier-duty command, `git filter-branch`, whose purpose is to copy commits while applying some sort of commit-modifier(s).  It has a lot of options because it's inherently very slow; but fundamentally, it consists of:

- List out every commit (by hash ID) to be operated-on.  In your case, that's simply "every commit".  Also, create an empty map of old hash ID → new hash ID.
- Then, starting from the root-most (oldest/most-ancestral) commit:

  1. Extract the commit into a temporary working area.
  2. Apply each of the various filters.
  3. Build a new commit from the result.  Use the hash map to map the parent ID(s) so that the new commit points back to an earlier-copied new commit.  This gives the command the new commit's hash ID.
  4. Add an entry to the map from old commit hash → new commit hash.
- Finally, after doing the above for every commit to be filtered, loop over all the *references* that you tell it to change (mostly branch names, but tag names too if you use a `--tag-name-filter`):

  1. Rename the original reference from `refs/whatever` to `refs/original/refs/whatever`.
  2. Create a new `refs/whatever` using the new hash found in the map.

At the end of this process, you have all the original commits (with `refs/original` to refer to them) plus all the new commits (using the branch names).

If you only have one branch name (and no tags), the only name you need to supply is this one branch name, probably `master`, but `--all` will tell Git to look at all references, and `--tag-name-filter cat` will tell Git that the change it should make to the tag names as it updates them is to make no change after all.

The `--tree-filter` directs `git filter-branch` that, for step 1 (extract commit), it should do the full and complete extraction, to a temporary directory that `git filter-branch` will construct on its own.  (Other filter options attempt to get away with a much faster extract-only-to-temporary-index trick.)  The command or commands you supply to `tree-filter` are run in this temporary directory, so if all you need to do is rename a file, the command:

```
mv old-relative-path new-relative-path
```

suffices (assuming a Unix/Linux-ish system).

Comment: Thanks so much for this. So to clarify: if I only want to run this on my feature branch, the full command would be `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mv old-relative-path new-relative-path' my-feature-branch` - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, though I recommend using `-- my-feature-branch` at the end there (the `--` is intended to be optional, and should be for *this* case, but it's best to use it before any `<rev-list option>`, lest you get surprised later when you go to do something fancier). This assumes `mv` is the correct command for renaming something, i.e., a Unix-like system.

Comment: Thanks @torek. I'm marking this answer as accepted because now that I've had some time to read up on it, it seems to be the right way to do this, and it is very informative and hopefully will be useful to others. In my case, I wanted a quick/simple solution, and so ended up just doing the naive approach I suggested in the question: an interactive rebase, where I moved the file in the first commit and then dealt with the conflicts one by one, which was actually not that bad in the end: I just had to keep running the same commands: `mv old/path new/path`, `git add -A`, `git rebase --continue`.